# Can't connect to windows server with rdesktop - “No valid license available” error

Tags: linux, windows, remote-desktop, linux-mint, windows-server

Im using Remotedesktop Client 0.23 on Linux Mint. When im trying to connect to a windows server, I get the following error: Disconnect: No valid license available

I know that I'm supposed to delete a file, but I can't find it.

Anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this blog](http://www.bramschoenmakers.nl/en/node/753) this happens because a temporary licence is generated for the system, expires and for some reason is not replaced. The 'harder' workaround is to change your hostname. You can however provide a fake hostname explicitly, with something like `rdesktop -n aoeuidhtns rdp.example.net` - the -n sends a hostname to the server, and in this case its just random garbage.

Credit where credit is due, found this answer from a now deleted comment by [Wutnaut](https://superuser.com/users/309028/wutnaut), which for some inexplicable reason, wasn't actually posted as an answer, nor linked directly to the blog post.